# Updating product in the catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, import, crud

I've some code to import some products: if the prodocut is new, I've insert it in the catalog, otherwise, I've to update the product if there are some changes.
Code is the following:

```
<?php

    include_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php');

    Mage::app();

    $rootMagento = mage::getBaseDir();
    $files = scandir($rootMagento);
    $count = sizeof($files);
    for ($i =0; $i< $count; $i++) {
        if ($files[$i]=='productData.txt'){   
            //$fileAperto = fopen($files[$i], "r");
            $righe = file('productData.txt');
            $countRighe = sizeof($righe);
            for ($ii = 0; $ii < $countRighe; $ii++) {
                list($sku, $name, $description, $shortDescription) = split("[';']", $righe[$ii]);
                if ($sku == '' || $name == '' || $description == '' 
                    || $shortDescription == '' ) {
                    mage::log('esportazione non corretta: manca uno dei dati');
                } 
                $product_model = mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $productId = $product_model->getIdBySku($sku);
                if (!$productId){
                    //inserimento
                    $productData = array ('sku' => $sku,
                                          'name' => $name,
                                          'description' => $description,
                                          'short_description' => $shortDescription,
                                          'status' => 1,
                                          'visibility' => 4,
                                          'attribute_set_id' => 10
                                          );

                    $product_model->setData($productData);
                    $qty = 1;
                    try{
                        $productId = $product_model->save()->getId();
                        $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                        $product->setQty($qty);
                        $product->setIsInStock(1); //->isInStock(1)
                        $product->save();

                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        mage::log($e->getMessage());
                    }

                }else{
                    //aggiornamento
                    $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                    $productData = array ('sku' => $sku,
                                          'name' => $name,
                                          'description' => $description,
                                          'short_description' => $shortDescription,
                                          'status' => 1,
                                          'visibility' => 4,
                                          'attribute_set_id' => 10
                                          );
                    $product->setData($productData); // + codice x stock
                    $qty = 1;
                    try{
                        $productId = $product_model->save()->getId();
                        $product = $product_model->load($productId);
                        $product->setQty($qty);
                        $product->setIsInStock(1); //->isInStock(1)
                        $product->save();

                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        mage::log($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**For the insert it's ok, but for update it doesn't work**. Isn't this code correct?

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed a small issue in your `else`.

Your code looks like this:

```
$product = $product_model->load($productId);
...
$productId = $product_model->save()->getId();
```

But the second line is wrong. If I get rid of the `$product_model` variable it looks like this:

```
$productId = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->save()->getId();
```

So **it does not work obviously as you need to save the product you loaded.**

So you need to replace this line with:

```
$productId = $product->save()->getId();
```

Comment: @Federica feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others ;)

Comment: I replaced the row and I used variable $product instead $product_model but the product didn't update. In my example I changed name of an existing product..

Comment: @Federica well I don't see any other errors in your code sorry I'm out of ideas here

Answer (score 0):

channge below line in your code

`$product_model = mage::getModel('catalog/product');`

to

`$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') 
                        ->loadByAttribute('sku', trim($sku) );`

and then you can get product id by `$product_model->getId();`  and name `$product_model->getName();`

and so on please let me know if you still find issue

Your product model is not loaded at update time that is why its not being save and replace above code it loads your model via `sku` and then you can update your product.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I tryied in this way but I've this error

Comment: change this line in update . from           `$productId = $product_model->save()->getId();`    to               `$productId = $product->save()->getId();`

Comment: Please check and let me know

Comment: I had already modified this row..

Comment: change this line from    `$product = $product_model->load($productId);`    to `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);`

Comment: there's not syntax errors but product name is always the same..

Comment: Yes that is why i am suggesting this change because my above line create new instance all time and data save differently

Comment: A strange thing happens: I'm doing some debug and I tryied to print old name using thi function $name = $product->getName(); and printed value is correct but, from the Magento panel, attribute 'name' is different (it's remained old value) despite I refreshed the page..